# make grid layout divs to be the same height

Tags: reactjs, sass, grid, display

I am trying to make my grid layout divs to be the same height. Please see my sass code below, screenshots of website [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5IHr.png) and  [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNjyS.png). I want the common height to be the height of the grid element with the most content.

I am only able to provide a picture of my html, since I am using react and different elements.

Please advise on SASS settings. thanks!

SASS code:

```
// MAIN CONTENT
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 114rem;
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
    margin:1rem;
    
    grid-template-columns: repeat(
      auto-fit,
      minmax(20rem, 1fr)
    );
    align-items: start;
    
    @include media(small) {
        grid-gap: 3rem;
     }
    
    &__item {
      background: $mainWhite;
      border-radius: 0.05rem;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
      transition: $transition;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
      
      &:hover {
        transform: translateY(-.5%);
        box-shadow: 0 4rem 8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  .card {
    .card__img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 18rem;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: top;
     }
    
    .card__content {
      padding: 2rem 2rem;
    a{
      margin-bottom: 1%;
      &:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
      }  
    }
    .card__tools__header{
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      color:$mainBlack;
    }
    .card__tools__box{
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      .card__tools {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color:$mainGreen;
        padding-right:1rem;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    }
    
    .card__header {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: $mainBlack;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
    .card__text {
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      letter-spacing: .1rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
        
    }
    .card__btn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 1rem;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      text-align: center;
      color: $mainBlack;
      background-color: $mainWhite;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      transition: $transition;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 5%;
      
      span {
        margin-left: 1rem;
      }
      
      &:hover,
      &:active {
        background: $mainGreen;
        text-decoration: none;
        color:$mainWhite;
          span {
          margin-left: 1.5rem;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height with `grid-template-rows` on your container and tell the children to fill 100% of that height. Otherwise they will only take the space they need:

```
.grid {
  //...
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;

  &__item {
    //...
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/mdVwpMY) for you to test this.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gh05d, this worked perfectly!!!! However, now I am facing another issue - I do have too much white space below each button in a card(or grid__item). I just need to position each button at the end of  grid__item. I've experimented with display:flex, but wasn't able to solve it.